# SocketIO (docker replicas) + Nginx + Browser = dulicated emit events by total of replicas

Tags: docker, nginx, flask-socketio

I have a SocketIO server run inside `docker swarm + Nginx for load balancing` which is working fine.

But I have a small problem with duplicated emit events.

Example: I have 30 replicas (copies) of `SocketIO server`; `1 Nginx gateway` and Everything running in `Docker Swarm`

My Nginx config:

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name  10.10.10.212;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
    # enable WebSockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
 }
```

My SocketIO server emit

```
socketio.emit('warehouse_scan:added', 'HB10790')
```

Browser result

[image: 30 results]

How can I solve this?

Comment: You haven't included the definition of `loadbalancer` in your nginx configuration. Can you add that?

Comment: @Miguel dear, it's a list of servers and workable. I just discovered the problem!

Answer (score 0):

duplicated events on emit is my false.
I set wrong parameter while setting up everything with nginx , match client versions , etc ...

Wrong config in backend:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, policy_server=True, async_mode='eventlet', manage_session=True, cors_allowed_origins="*", message_queue=socket_io_msg_q)
```

The correct one that fixed duplication:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, engineio_logger=True, policy_server=True, async_mode='eventlet', manage_session=True)
```

The problem is at this line:

```
message_queue=socket_io_msg_q <-- error!
```

This will trigger all emit events from backend server to REDIS then get back to client. If i have 50 replicas, clients will receive the amount of message from these replicas.